# how to put scroll view in collapsing toolbar layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

**I want something similar to below asked question where instead of 'view 1' ,it's going to be a scroll view :**
[android: Create layout which collapse on scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757965/android-create-layout-which-collapse-on-scrolling)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#456342"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">



            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/activity_subcard_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>



            <include layout="@layout/activity_sub_card_content1"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <include layout="@layout/activity_sub_card_content2" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Given below xml code is my layout 'activity_sub_card_content1' that i have included in my CollapsingToolbarLayout. i want something similar to this:

[image]

[How to place a layout below toolbar in collapsing toolbar layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386184/how-to-place-a-layout-below-toolbar-in-collapsing-toolbar-layout)

but it has a relative layout that is not too long. Mine will be long,so i want to put my layout in scroll view.

The code i have tried shows my scrollview,but it does not scroll it,instead it collapses the toolbar.

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/trial"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:clickable="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp">

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding these two lines in your code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
<Your code here with 
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add this tag

```
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/trial"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

----- your code

</ScrollView>
```

AppBarLayout also requires a separate scrolling sibling in order to know when to scroll. The binding is done through the  AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior class, meaning that you should set your scrolling view's behavior to be an instance of AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior. A string resource containing the full class name is available.

**Check this link:** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html