# Collapsing Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm working on android application just for learning purposes an in the app I have a Relative layout who has another linear layout in it and a RecyclerView. The RecyclerView is there to show a list of friends for the particular user and the Linear layout is to give an option to the user to click on it and to be redirected to another activity  where he can add new friends. This is the .xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/addFriendLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_new_friend"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/addNewFriendTextColor"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/friendsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addFriendLayout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want to do?

-When the user scroll up I want that Linear layout to hide behind the toolbar and then when user scroll down to collapse and become visible.

This is one similar case like mine but I didn't understand how to do it. 
[Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757965/android-create-layout-which-collapse-on-scrolling)

Answer (score 2):

check this code.. I hope this may help you

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="44dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="20dp">

                 <!--your design here-->

              </LinearLayout>
             <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```